Would an LEO asking for a race constitute entrapment?
This happened in Virginia, many years ago.  Nothing happened, but I have a hypothetical question.
My friend and I were out driving in his car.  He drives a classic muscle car, a 1969 Cutlass Supreme 442 convertible.  A marked police squad car pulls up next to us at a red light.  The in-uniform officer in the car was - and I feel it was genuine - geeking out over my friend's car.  He then asked if we wanted to race (drag race).  My friend thanked him and said no.  We then drove off - normally - at the green light.
Obviously, nothing happened.  However, what if he said yes?  The light turns green, he floors it, and then officer pulls him over.  While my friend does like fast cars, he is actually surprisingly responsible with them and has no history of anything other than a few speeding tickets.  Would that be entrapment?

"he is actually surprisingly responsible with them and has no history of anything other than a few speeding tickets" Your friend would do well to alter his behavior before he ends up in a serious accident. Collecting multiple speeding tickets is a sure sign of non-responsible driving. Nobody has "a history of anything", until they do, and every driver thinks they know road safety better than the local authorities who set the limits.

@UJM That's a bit naive, since those "local authorities" are sometimes known to place unexpected speed limit signs primarily for revenue generation rather than safety. It's a stretch to say "a sure sign of non-responsible driving" without knowing the circumstances and especially the total length/scope of driving record. Yes, no tickets is always better than some -- but say if a driver, over decades of heavy travel in diverse places, falls for a few unfamiliar speed traps but has never had an accident/collision, that sounds consistent with being a responsible driver.

@UJM Yes, mother.

@UJM The reason I mentioned the speeding tickets is to show he is not inclined to drag race, as he has no tickets for racing, reckless, etc.  Everybody has exceeded the speed limit many times in their life, whether or not they received a ticket for it.

"Collecting multiple speeding tickets is a sure sign of non-responsible driving." - That seems like a bit of an overreaction, especially without knowing how many speeding tickets over what period, for what speed, and in what situation.

@nanoman I grant you the relevant metric is tickets-per-distance-traveled rather than tickets, but the rest of my point stands. In my experience (in France), people who complain about "speed traps" never say "I chose to ignore the stupid limit as an act of civil disobedience". They say "how could I see the sign in time to control my speed on that downward slope / in that curb / in the dark". Well... If you could not see driving-related information and act on it in time, that means you were a danger.

It doesn't sound like entrapment because, simply, the police man was not "in disguise", it was evidently and openly an officer.  Cool question though.

Can you edit in some photos of the car?

@UJM "Collecting multiple speeding tickets is a sure sign of non-responsible driving" that's simply not true.  moreover, it's totally off topic - which can be very confusing on this site.  A HUGE problem on this site is when folks drift to general life advice rather than addressing the literal legal question :O

@UJM speeds in France (I mean on the autoroute) are just incredibly high! I actually believe they are the highest typically in the world, in my vast experience.    I LOVE driving in France!  Also, all the speed camera points are very well known and (not never but rarely) move or are mobile, so it's perfect, and of course the autoroute system is presently by far the best and fastest set of roads on Earth - viva !!

@UJM I got about 6 speeding tickets so far, 4 of them for less than 5kmh over the limit, spread out over a period of 32 years. I've never had an accident caused by speed (2 accidents, both well under the speed limit, caused by circumstances outside of my control, neither caused injury or death). Am I an irresponsible driver?

The defense might be "entrapment", or might involve a slight different defense that would protect the drag racing driver.
Under the U.S. Supreme Court cases of United States v. Laub, 385 U.S. 475 (1967), Cox v. Lousiana, 379 U.S. 559 (1965), and Raley v. Ohio, 360 U.S. 423 (1959), a defendant may not be punished for actions taken in good faith reliance upon authoritative assurances that he will not be punished for those actions.
Entrapment doesn't involve a belief that someone has authoritatively assured you that you won't be punished. It usually (but not always) also involves a lack of knowledge that the people egging you on are government agents. As explained at the link above:

"Government agents may not originate a criminal design, implant in an
innocent person's mind the disposition to commit a criminal act, and
then induce commission of the crime so that the Government may
prosecute." Jacobson v. United States, 503 U.S. 540, 548
(1992). A valid entrapment defense has two related elements: (1)
governmentinducement of the crime, and (2) the defendant's lack of
predisposition to engage in the criminal conduct. Mathews v. United
States, 485 U.S. 58, 63 (1988). Of the two elements, predisposition is by far the more important.

It is not entirely clear which of these doctrines would apply.

So it's more likely to be entrapment if the police officer convinces you to race him when out of uniform, then pulls out his badge and arrests you.

Interesting.  And coming from  SCOTUS too.

@Barmar Yes. That's correct.

@ohwilleke Am I incorrect in detecting that that distinction is just customary, though? The cited 2 elements seem to be entirely present if a uniformed police officer tries to convince an otherwise uninclined person to take part in drag racing, even if the unlucky drag-racer never thought to ask "and I won't be arrested?"

@user99478 It might hinge on whether such an assumption counts as "authoritative assurances" in the judge's opinion.

@user99478 That's why I hedged and said one or the other. A uniform isn't necessary for entrapment, but is a much more typical fact pattern.

@Barmar "So it's more likely to be entrapment if the police officer convinces you to race him when out of uniform, then pulls out his badge and arrests you" if you think about it, that sentence is literally an exact example of exactly entrapment! so "yes" I guess!

@ohwilleke amazing case law examples you pulled up !!!  bravo

@Fattie Right, but the point of my comment was to highlight the difference between actual entrapment and the OP's scenario.

@Barmar yes I completely understand, it came out unintentionally humorously since a perfect match.  :)

@Fattie IRL if I were litigating the issue in Virginia, I would far prefer to have Virginia appellate court cases implementing the SCOTUS decisions than the SCOTUS decisions themselves.

@Fattie I see your point. There are many confusing examples (e.g. it's not entrapment if a cop poses as a hooker because if john was already planning on soliciting someone), but this is pretty clear-cut.

Yes, I was strictly making a joke, socially pointing out something incidentally funny, completely unrelated to the QA.   :)  It's the humor pattern where you incrementally increase statements or considerations and finally - "I guess that would do it!"   you've arrive at and state the exact definition sentence whilst still just incrementally increasing.

(that's the most difficult "humor pattern" I have ever had to precis, and I do it for a living, heh!)

@Fattie: Empirically, he probably has this pair of cases in his back pocket for this sort of question.  It makes me suspect this topic comes up a lot, either with his clients or on the internet in general.

@Brian an ingenious comment on an ingenious defense !

@Brian I do. It is a key set of cases in marijuana business law which is about a third of my law practice.

As a retired LEO I have a few thoughts about this. Under the U.S. v Laub, Cox v Louisiana, and Raley v Ohio cases cited here, one would have to have act upon a "good faith reliance" from a "authoritative assurance [emphasis added]" that they believe that they wouldn't be punished for committing a crime. I think that it would be quite difficult to convince any judge that 1) the officer enticed you to race with impunity, and 2) that a reasonable person would believe that an officer that was actively encouraging you to race on the public roadways, thereby placing the public in danger, had any such authority to do so. I think that you lack both a good faith reliance (you know it's wrong and you know that the officer is wrong for encouraging it) and an authoritative assurance (don't think an officer who is clearly acting outside of his authority can provide any form an an assurance that is "authoritative"). Imagine if the officer told you to rob the bank with him and he tells you that it's okay because he's an officer. Just doesn't fly.
Entrapment doesn't work either. This concept is pretty simple. The government actively encourages you to take an illegal act that you wouldn't have taken absent that persuasion, with the intent of prosecuting you for it. A significant question here is whether the officer is acting as an agent of the government. Most of the times the answer would be yes, but in this instance the officer would clearly be operating outside of the authority vested in him by the government. Even when you view the evidence in a manner that is most favorable to the driver, which I think the law would require in most places, I don't think you can overcome significant obstacles in this defense.
If you add to the scenario a bit it becomes a little easier to see how this would play out in reality. Imagine the cars racing down the highway and one of them crashing into another vehicle, killing one of the occupants. Being that both individuals were involved in a "crime" that resulted in a death, both individuals are now responsible for that death, regardless of the fact that one of them happens to be an on-duty officer. You're going to need more than a "but he told me to" defense.

interesting view.  I do see what you mean by saying we know drag racing is wrong, regardless of what the officer says.  However, I think its safe to say when a police officer tells you to do something, most people will do it.  Now he didnt tell us to drag race, but I do think its not unreasonable for people to think that it was implied.  That being said, if a police officer said go ahead and jaywalk, I think I would feel ok doing it.  However, if the officer said murder someone, I wouldnt.  Obviously, this situation lies in between.

And you said it’s risky because the officer could lie in court and would be believed. @Keltari: In traffic, a police officer can see a situation and override the rules. So if he tells you to cross the road, then it’s not jaywalking. Like you can drive through a stop sign if you have a green traffic light and you can drive through a red traffic light if an officer tells you.
